# how to change background color by changing the theme in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-theme

I want to change the background color when I change the theme in android. Is there a way to set the background in XML like

```
android:background="@styles/colorAccent"
```

so when I change the theme the background color automatically changes to the colorAccent of the respective theme. Any alternate approach would also help.

Comment: you should manually change the background based on the theme selected and you need to change it manyally, there's no short path for that

Comment: actually i want to implement different themes for the app by button click,i want to change the theme so all the colors automatically get changed if i follow this approach , i would have to add check for each and every view, which would not be feasible way to do it .

Comment: You should create multiple theme for it, and add background property inside each theme separately then only you can achieve it

Comment: kindly give one short example with small code snippet , i would be able to understand better .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample layout

```
 <FrameLayout
    style="@style/colorAccentStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content/>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="colorAccentStyle">
    <item name="android:background">?colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Simpler solution

```
<FrameLayout
    android:background="?colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create different themes with this attribute

```
<style name="YourTheme" >
<item name="android:background">@color/yourcolor</item>
</style>
```

This will get applied for the views where there's no background set manually.

Finally you can apply your theme by

```
getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.YourTheme, true);
```

calling this before `setContentView`